Error when intersecting 2 sf objected which have the same CRS
I have two spatial SF objects:

veg_plots_2024

Reading layer `veg_plots_2024' from data source 
  `C:\XXXX\veg_plots_2024.shp' 
  using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 940 features and 40 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 170071.9 ymin: 26088.89 xmax: 646894 ymax: 640827.2
Projected CRS: OSGB36 / British National Grid


land_class

Reading layer `land_class' from data source 
  `C:\XXXX\land_class.shp' 
  using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 45 features and 5 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 54 ymin: 11 xmax: 656 ymax: 1218
Projected CRS: OSGB36 / British National Grid

I want to intersect the two, to understand which land classes the veg plots fall into. I would have thought this was quite a simple use of:
st_intersection(veg_plots_2024, land_class)

But i repeatedly get the below error:
Error in st_geos_binop("intersects", x, y, sparse = sparse, prepared = prepared,  : 
  st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE

I'm unsure how to proceed as the CRS seems the same and this function works with other datasets, just not the land_class one. Could it be an issue with the Bounding box?
Thanks in advance
I have tried to transform the CSR but it gave me further errors
EDIT for further info as requested in comments below:
> cat(st_crs(land_class)$wkt)
PROJCRS["OSGB36 / British National Grid",
    BASEGEOGCRS["OSGB36",
        DATUM["Ordnance Survey of Great Britain 1936",
            ELLIPSOID["Airy 1830",6377563.396,299.3249646,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6277]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",49,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-2,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.999601272,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",400,
            LENGTHUNIT["kilometre",1000],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",-100,
            LENGTHUNIT["kilometre",1000],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["kilometre",1000,
                ID["EPSG",9036]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["kilometre",1000,
                ID["EPSG",9036]]]]


The CRS is not necessarily the same if one of the data sets (most likely land_class) is older. The switch from PROJCS to PROJCRS might explain the problem.
You can easily solve this with st_intersection(st_transform(veg_plots_2024, crs=st_crs(land_class), land_class) (or vice versa). Look here

Unless land_class is looking at small patch of sea off the Scilly Isles it is not in OSGB (27700). The coordinates are too small (but oddly too big to be WGS84 either).

Can you edit the question to show the underlying WKT representation of the two objects? Use cat(st_crs(x)$wkt) to show the text. Check for differences. It does look like your second layer has odd coordinate numbers - maybe its been scaled by 1000 relative to the other layer and there's a UNITS parameter different... If you could show or share just the .prj files (these look like they come from shapefiles) that would help...

@IanTurton this should be a database of multipolygons covering the whole of england so perhaps there is an inherent issue with the data itself
